# How to split string using strtok() in C?

Tags: c, string, split, strtok

I am trying to split strings with strtok, but I can't print the second part of my string.

```
 int main (void) {
     char str[128];
     char *ptr;

     strcpy (str, "123456 789asdf");
     strtok (str, " ", &ptr);

     printf ("'%s'  '%s'\n", str, ptr);
     return 0;
 }
```

the outcome is something like this:

```
'123456' '12jfs90123#4'
```

Comment: How about reading the documentation of a function before using it?

Comment: In addition to the answers below I'd like to point out that you need to include the appropriate header too, in this case `#include <string.h>`. Also, `<stdio.h>` should be included for printf.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you've misunderstood how `strtok` works.

The second parameter is supposed to point to a string of delimiter characters. The "current" string is the return value. On the first call, you pass the string you want to split. On subsequent calls, you pass NULL for the first parameter.

`strtok` also modifies the string you pass to it, so you must *not* ever pass a string literal as the first parameter.

Working code normally looks at least a little more like this:

```
char input[] = "123456 789asdf";

char *substring = strtok(input, " ");

do { 
    printf("%s\n", substring);
} while (strtok(NULL, " "));
```

If, however, you know you're only going to look for two arguments, it's probably easier to use `scanf`:

```
char s1[256], s2[256];

sscanf(str, "%255s %255s", s1, s2);
```

Comment: Also probably OP is trying for `strtok_r`

Answer (score 1):

[`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) works a bit differently than the way you used it:

```
char str[] = "123456 789asdf";

char* token = strtok (str, " ");
char* token2 = strtok (NULL, " ");
printf ("'%s'  '%s'\n", token, token2);
```

outputs the desired: `'123456'  '789asdf'`

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep calling [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) until it returns NULL, as strtok returns one token resulting from the splitting at every function call.
This is working code:

```
int main (void) {
    char str[128];
    char *ptr;

    strcpy (str, "123456 789asdf");
    ptr = strtok (str, " ");

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf ("'%s'\n", ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return 0;
 }
```